# INSERT INTO new table setting Primary Key

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL command that converts from seconds to HH:MM:SS. It creates new tables as it gets the seconds from the original table. Is there a way to set the primary key of the name column when it creates the new tables? Here is the SQL I am using:

```
SELECT 
    main.[Name], 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Staffed Time] / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((main.[Staffed Time] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)  + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Staffed Time] % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS StaffedTime, 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Break] / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((main.[Time in Break] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)  + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Break] % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS BreakTime, 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Lunch] / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((main.[Time in Lunch] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)  + ':' +
       RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Lunch] % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS LunchTime
INTO
    DailyReport
FROM   
    main
```

I know I could make another alter table command that will set it for me like this:

```
ALTER TABLE main
ADD PRIMARY KEY (Name)
```

I was hoping there was a way to have it set the PK as soon as it's created, is this possible?

Comment: `DailyReport` is newly created right??

Comment: You really should get in the habit of specifying a length with varchar. Otherwise it uses the default, do you know what that is? Do you know that the default changes depending on where it is used? I suspect that query could be simplified a bit too but it is entirely to jumbled to make much sense of it.

Comment: any specifications I use mainly get edited before the roll out, but you are right. I only provide testing data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before inserting data try to create new table variable with `PRIMARY KEY` set.
Try below code

```
CREATE TABLE DailyReport (
                     ID INT Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
                     [Name] NVARCHAR(30) ,
                     StaffedTime NVARCHAR(30), 
                     BreakTime NVARCHAR(30),
                     LunchTime NVARCHAR(30)
                    )

INSERT INTO DailyReport
SELECT main.[Name], 
 RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Staffed Time] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
 RIGHT('0' + CAST((main.[Staffed Time] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
 RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Staffed Time] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
 AS StaffedTime, 
 RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Break] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
 RIGHT('0' + CAST((main.[Time in Break] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
 RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Break] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) 
 AS BreakTime, 
 RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Lunch] / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
 RIGHT('0' + CAST((main.[Time in Lunch] / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
 RIGHT('0' + CAST(main.[Time in Lunch] % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) 
 AS LunchTime
FROM main

SELECT * FROM DailyReport
```

Comment: IT shows that 49 rows are affected but the table is not being created.

Comment: At end Try to fire `SELECT * FROM @DailyReport` so that u will get data

Comment: this is excellent! however the table is still not creating (this is needed as the DailyReport table is a hub for many other SQL Commands)

Comment: This is fantastic, I will do some additional testing cause it adds IDs as a column which I prefer to have Names as PK instead of a generated ID. If I'm able to work well with these IDs I will mark as answered after the testing.

Comment: This is also what I was needing on another Table that I'm working on the same project, so really I killed 2 birds with one stone on this question. Thank you Jay

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create `primary key constraint` automatically. You either:

- explicitly create table with PRIMARY KEY defined and have a n INSERT ... INTO

OR

- use `SELECT INTO` table and alter it by adding the PK constraint (`ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tablename PRIMARY KEY (col_name)`)

**Tip:** try to always use named constraints, as it is much easier to change (drop) them if name is fixed (not server generated)

Comment: when I tried this. I got an error stating that the PK cannot bet set on collumns that allow null values. Is this because I'm not declaring Nullible = 'False' in the command for that column? If so how can I make this column not nullible.=?

Comment: Yes, that column should be not null. One way is to change nullable property like this: `ALTER TABLE newTable ALTER COLUMN col INT NOT NULL` before trying to put a PK constraint for it.

Comment: Only INT is not going to work as [Name] is of course varchar. So I replaced INT with VARCHAR and I get a message:

String or binary data would be truncated. Statement has been terminated.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE newTable ALTER COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL` - 255 is an example, it should be chosen based on your column size.

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting. Thank you Alexei.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
ALTER TABLE DailyReport
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Name PRIMARY KEY (Name);
```